# Ошибка при mysql запросе DateDiff

Tags: mysql, access

Вечер добрый!
Нужна помощь с запросом

`SELECT worker.birth, DateDiff('yyyy',worker.birth,Date()) AS Y FROM worker;`

В MS Access работает, но перетаскиваю в phpmyadmin - ничего.

Answer (score 1):

в `MySQL` у функции `DateDiff` 2 входящих параметра, см.  [док](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

правельнее будет

```
SELECT worker.birth, DateDiff(worker.birth,Date()) AS Y FROM worker;
```

Comment: Спасибо! работает